# Adding android:textIsSelectable causes TextView to autoscroll

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, scrollview

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/solutions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="1.  1+2+3 = 6"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

After adding `android:textIsSelectable="true"` to the `TextView`, the `TextView` will auto-scroll to bottom. However I do not want this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For people with the same problem: You have two Scrollviews, you might need to play around a bit or use NestedScrollView.
In the end this worked for me:

> **android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants**

on the parent of my TextView

Try this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
       android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/solutions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="1.  1+2+3 = 6"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView> </ScrollView>
```

UPDATE: Although this seemed to work, it didn't. The view just jumped randomly so in my tests it looked fine at first.

I can't find a proper solution so I'm using dirty hacks. My textview is now "nonselectable". In my onCreateView() of my Fragment, I wait 1,5 seconds in a new thread and update the textview from the UI thread AFTER the Fragment view is fully build. That way the textview is not re-focused and the scrollview doesn't jump around:

```
        Runnable x = () -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1500);
                if(getActivity()!=null){

                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        textview.setFocusable(true);
                       textview.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        textview.setTextIsSelectable(true);
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        new Thread(x).start();
```

Answer (score -1):

try this: add

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/solutions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        android:text="1.  1+2+3 = 6"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

The reason of the solution is :

When you use `android:textIsSelectable="true"`, you're essentially calling `TextView.setTextIsSelectable(true)`, which makes calls to both `View.setFocusable` and `View.setFocusableInTouchMode.`...and causes the `scrollview` to automatically scroll the text.

Comment: That makes the text unselectable

Comment: Pleas tell us more about your idea.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42761382/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I confirm this makes the text unselectable on API 23, so it's useless.

Comment: Result Logcat: TextView W TextView does not support text selection. Selection cancelled.